# Equivalent definitions of (dis)continuous phase transitions at criticality

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, spin-models, critical-phenomena

Consider a classical lattice model on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and suppose that the system undergoes a phase transition as you lower the temperature, i.e., increase $\beta$. The most general definition of a first-order (discontinuous) transition (as far as I know) is that it is discontinuous if (1) the Gibbs measure (satisfying the DLR condition) is non-unique at criticality $\beta_c$. Conversely, it is continuous if the Gibbs state is unique at criticality.

I'm curious why this is equivalent to other definitions of continuous/discontinuous phase transitions, such as (2) the correlation length diverges/finite and (3) the magnetization is zero/nonzero.

Indeed, I know that for the q-states Potts model on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, it was proven (I think by Hugo Duminil-Cupin) that (2) and (3) are equivalent. I also think there's a counter example for (3) by Aernout van enter, who shown that for a family of 2D XY spin model (not the standard XY model), the transition is discontinuous, even though by Mermin-Wagner, the magnetization must be zero. However, the model seemed relatively "unphysical".

With that in mind, my **question** is, are there theorems that show equivalence between definitions (1) and (2) or (1) and (3) for relatively general spin systems?

Comment: http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html -- have you seen this book?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Yes, I quite like the book, but I don't think it focuses on criticality that much.